# Firefox ignoring format-detection on iPhone

Tags: html, firefox

In the following HTML, Firefox on iPhone is rendering 30 thru 60 as a phone number, despite the meta tag asking it not to do so. Is this a known bug, or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

```
<html>
    <head>
            <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            ul.filters li {
                display:inline-block;
            }
        </style>
        <ul class="filters">
            <li>30</li>
            <li>35</li>
            <li>40</li>
            <li>45</li>
            <li>50</li>
            <li>55</li>
            <li>60</li>
            <li>65</li>
            <li>70</li>
            <li>75</li>
            <li>80</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by adding characters to each `<li>` element. My code example is an age filter, so I amended each `<li>` like this:

```
<li>30+</li>
<li>35+</li>
```

etc. I tried wrapping the + signs in `<span>` tags and making them invisible, but Firefox was persisting in turning them into a phone number. So the next best option was to use a CSS `font-size` value of 1px as follows:

```
<li>30<span class="font-size:1px;">+</span></li>
<li>35<span class="font-size:1px;">+</span></li>
```

etc, and that seems to be enough to discourage Firefox.